# How to continue main bullet after a nested bullet list?

Tags: gmail

I am writing a message in Gmail with bullet lists.

After I create a nested bullet list, I do not know how to return to the parent list item without creating a new main-level bullet. Something like:

```
* Main Item 1
  - nested item 1
  - nested item 2
  Main Item 1 continues
* Main Item 2
```

I tried achieving that in many ways, but "Main Item 1 continues" either becomes part of "nested item 2", or obtains a new main-level bullet as if it was a separate item.

In Google Docs, this can be easily achieved. After "nested item 2" I can just:

- Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- Press the "Decrease Indent" button
- Press <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>

In Google Docs, the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> removes the bullet, but I remain in the line I started with, allowing me to write a paragraph that would be part of the previous main item bullet point. In Gmail, however, the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> completely removes the end-of-line, and I return back to "nested item 2".

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail's web app message editor is relatively simple. The good news is that nowadays, Google Docs and Gmail are integrated directly by Google to use Google Docs to write email draft messages. To learn more about this relatively new feature, please read [Use Google Docs to draft emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/11930385?hl=en). Try this to understand if this feature satisfies your needs.